# MongoDB query to find fields with common value and return all the details of those fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection as follows:

Collection: movies

```
[
      {"_id": 0,title: "Movie A",  year: 2010, director: "D1", actors: ["A1","A2"] }
      ,{"_id": 1,title: "Movie B",  year: 2010, director: "D1", actors: ["A1","A5","A6"]}
      ,{"_id": 2,title: "Movie C",  year: 2010, director: "D2", actors: ["A4"]}
      ,{"_id": 3,title: "Movie D",  year: 2012, director: "D3", actors: ["A7"]}
      ,{"_id": 4,title: "Movie E",  year: 2015, director: "D3", actors: ["A7"]}
]
```

I want to return all movie details when the director is the same, that is records with common directors.

The result should be like this:

```
 {"_id": 0,title: "Movie A",  year: 2010, director: "D1", actors: ["A1","A2"] },
 {"_id": 1,title: "Movie B",  year: 2010, director: "D1", actors: ["A1","A5","A6"]},
 {"_id": 3,title: "Movie D",  year: 2012, director: "D3", actors: ["A7"]},
 {"_id": 4,title: "Movie E",  year: 2015, director: "D3", actors: ["A7"]}
```

I tried this:

```
db.movies.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$director",count : {$sum : 1}}},{$match:{"count":{$gt:1}}},])
```

and got a result:

```
{ "_id" : "D3", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "D1", "count" : 2 }
```

but don't know what to do next?

Comment: How _id;2 was removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$group` by `director`, get total count by sum and construct the array of all movies in `rootDocs` property
- `$match` to filter the document that count is greater than 1
- `$unwind` deconstruct the `rootDocs` array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `rootDocs` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$director",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      rootDocs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } },
  { $unwind: "$rootDocs" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$rootDocs" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8R_2DIAmA4K)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation where we did following pipeline stages:

1. Group: to put movies with same directors together
2. Match: to find common director i.e director should have at least 2 movies
3. unwind: as you need single/original records so we need to unwind/ungroup records
4. project: to get result in expected format will map the grouped data into original schema.

   ```
    [{$group: {
   _id: '$director',
   commonDirector: {
    $addToSet: '$$ROOT'
   },
   count:{$sum:1}
   }}, {$match: {
   count: {$gt:1}
   }}, {$unwind: {
   path: '$commonDirector',
   preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
   }}, {$project: {
    _id: '$commonDirector._id',
   title: '$commonDirector.title',
   year:'$commonDirector.year',
   director:"$commonDirector.director",
   actors:'$commonDirector.actors'
   }}, {
   $sort: {
    director: 1,
    title:1
      }
   }]
   ```

then it produces the result the way you want:

```
 {"_id": 0,title: "Movie A",  year: 2010, director: "D1", actors: ["A1","A2"] },
 {"_id": 1,title: "Movie B",  year: 2010, director: "D1", actors: ["A1","A5","A6"]},
 {"_id": 3,title: "Movie D",  year: 2012, director: "D3", actors: ["A7"]},
 {"_id": 4,title: "Movie E",  year: 2015, director: "D3", actors: ["A7"]}
```